# Interaction plot in factorial design

Tags: r, plot, factorial, interaction

How to investigate the effect of a main factor on a respone with ANOVA?

Comment: Can you share your data as well?

Comment: No problem. I added the data :)

Comment: difference in `y` is larger for `C` going from -1 to 1, than it is for `B` going from -1 to 1 (or from 1 to -1).

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily calculate the mean of y at different levels of A, B and C:

```r
by( y, B, mean ) # mean of y at each level
diff( by( y, B, mean ) ) # the difference of the means at the two available levels of y

# same for A and C:

by( y, C, mean )
# etc.
```

I don't really see your `newdata` variable that you plot, but assuming its just `data.frame(A,B,C,y)` , my figure matches the mean's of y at levels of predictors. Though my figure is slightly different from yours.